\varinjlim and \lim with quotation marks around (ind-lim and pro-lim in LaTeX)
None of the answers of this question solve my issue at hand. In Kashiwara, Schapira, Categories and Sheaves, p. 133, one can find this:

To reverse-engineer such “\varinjlim with quotation marks” (Chapter 6 of the quoted book, to which p. 133 belongs, is full of these) I came up with the following code that I added to my preamble:
\def\indlim#1{\underset{\underset{#1}{\longrightarrow}}{\text{\normalfont``lim''}\,}}
so that \indlim{i}\alpha(i)} will produce

However, my command \indlim is not perfect: Writing \indlim{i}\alpha(i)} \quad \varinjlim_i\alpha(i) gives

As you can see, the left one is not the same as the right one (up to quotation marks). The arrow position is not the same, nor is the size of the  under.
My question is: How could I effectively get something that looks exactly like \varinjlim but with quotation marks? An analogously with \varprojlim.
Also, I would like to have something that prints things in the exact manner that \lim does but with quotation marks around.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\quotinjlim{%
    \mathop{``\mathpalette\varlim@{\rightarrowfill@\textstyle}"}\nmlimits@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
    \quotinjlim_{i} \alpha(i)
    =
    \varinjlim_{i} \alpha(i)
\]

\end{document}


Old solution
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*\quotinjlim{``\underrightarrow{\lim}''}

\begin{document}

\[
    \quotinjlim_{i} \alpha(i)
    =
    \varinjlim_{i} \alpha(i)
\]

\end{document}

Meanwhile, my personal opinion is that the default arrows are too big and ugly. See this answer and this follow-up one for better solutions.


Thanks a bunch! What if I wanted to have just the word lim without an arrow? (And the word colim without an arrow.) I don't see how to edit your first solution to achieve this. I tried deleting several things but it won't compile (I don't understand your code, I haven't seen those commands before, nor I understand what @ does).

If you don’t want an arrow, it’s better to edit the second solution. Simply do \DeclareMathOperator*{\quotlim}{``lim''} and \DeclareMathOperator*{\quotcolim}{``colim''}. For an explanation about @ and \makeatletter...\makeatother, see e.g. this answer.
